# Are dates still good if they sat in a sealed bag in the sun?

Tags: food-safety, date-fruit

I had some groceries delivered and the dates were packaged in sealed plastic bags -- they got pretty hot sitting in the sun, so it was kinda sweating inside the bag. Are they still good?

Answer (score 1):

If these are dried dates you have no problem. Dried dates are often dried in the sun so having more sun on them isn't likely to be a problem. A bit of condensation isn't an issue, just air them out and put them in a cool, dry place.

If your dates are fresh they would need refrigeration as they aren't dried as much as fully dried dates, and it is harder to advise. Usually I would say throw them away but dates are pretty resilient so I would say to try a small bit of one and see if they still are good.

Your dates are probably dried by the way, most are. If they were fresh it would say on the store's website.

Comment: Just remember to keep six feet away from your dates. In these troubling times this also applies to fruits with benefits.